# Having a default image as a loading screen for nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to have my background as the loading screen between the page transitions in next js. Currently I have a Loader.js file that stores my image:-

```
import styles from './layout.module.css'

export default function Loader(){
    return(
        <div className={styles.loaderContainer}>
            <img src="../uploads/bg1080x1920.jpg" />
            <div>Loading ...</div> 
        </div>
    )
```

And in my _app.js I am using next/router for handling the routeChangeStart and routeChangeComplete events:

```
import {useState} from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Loader from "../components/Loader"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (url) => {
    console.log("Route is changing");
    setLoading(true)
  });
  router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", (url) => {
    console.log("Route is changed");
    setLoading(false)
  });

  return (
    <>
    {loading && <Loader />}
    <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

But I'm not able to get any console logs from my routeChangeStart and routeChangeComplete events when I try to switch to another page.

Comment: this can help https://vercel.com/blog/monorepos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js [examples](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), events registering is always inside an `useEffect` hook. I suggest you to modify you code like this:

```
import {useState, useEfffect} from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Loader from "../components/Loader"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => { //<-- this useEffect will be triggered just one time at component initialization
      router.events.on("routeChangeStart", (url) => {
         console.log("Route is changing");
         setLoading(true)
      });
      router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", (url) => {
         console.log("Route is changed");
         setLoading(false)
      });
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <>
    {loading && <Loader />}
    <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yea this solved the problem, but I'm still not able to get any console logs or my background as the loading screen

Comment: @JayModi this happens because you put `img` in div (and probably that img has width and height = 0). Try to put image as `backgroudImage` of `div` in class `loaderContainer`. You should see the image as backgroud.

Comment: I tried this too but there are still no logs being posted or image being loaded. Do you know any piece of code that could be preventing this from happening?

Comment: @JayModi for the image issue, have tried to check if `../uploads/bg1080x1920.jpg` is the correct path? And in case it is correct, have you tried to import image? Something like: `import bg from '../uploads/bg1080x1920.jpg';` and then `<img src={bg} />`?

Comment: Yes I tried it. The thing is the console logs that I have put in routeChangeStart and routeChangeComplete are not showing that means these events are not invoking hence the loader is not showing the image. So I think I have an error in the _app.js code. Here's my github link for further clarification(https://github.com/Jay-Bruh/TNA.git)